# Toy Soldiers Array

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

I have a large number of toy soldiers, which I can arrange into a rectangular array consisting of a number of rows and a number of columns. I notice that if I remove 100 toy soldiers, then I can arrange the remaining ones into a rectangular array with 5 fewer rows and 5 more columns. How many toy soldiers would I have to remove from the original configuration to be able to arrange the remaining ones into a rectangular array with 11 fewer rows and 11 more columns?

This is one of the last questions in a Mathematics Competition that I attempted. I honestly have no clue where to start when solving this question, I asked several maths teachers at my school, but they still haven't managed to find an answer. Any help with this question is appreciated.

Edit:
Since I was asked to show how I attempted to solve this question, here it is.

x = number of soldiers,
r = rows,
c = columns

In the original configuration, the statement x = r * c is true. In the second configuration, the statement x - 100 = (r - 5) * (c + 5) is true. This statement simplified is x = cr + 5r - 5c + 75. In both of these cases, I have three unknown variables. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Express the statements as algebraic equations, with unknowns, and simply solve them.

Comment: @David G. Stork Any other pointers? I mean, my maths teacher had to ask someone else to solve this problem, if it is as simple as you say, surely he could have done it?

Comment: Show your attempts in your problem, and you're far more likely to get help.

Comment: @David G. Stork That's the problem, I don't know where to start.

Comment: Do you have the answer?

Comment: @Meeta Jo I will try to find it, but it might take some time.

Comment: @Meeta Jo The answer is 286

Comment: From this quote "I notice that if I remove $100$ toy soldiers, then I can arrange the remaining ones into a rectangular array with $5$ fewer rows and $5$ ***more*** columns." Shouldn't your equation be $$rc-100=(r-5)(c+5)\,?$$

Comment: @Batominovski My mistake, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a sign wrong in one equation, so you should actually have the equations

$$n=rc\\
n-100=(r-5)(c+5)$$

where $r$, $c$ are the number of rows and columns, and $n$ is the total number of soldiers. Substituting $n$ gives:

$$rc-100=(r-5)(c+5)\\
rc-100=rc-5c+5r-25\\
c-r=15$$

What the question asks for is how many soldiers are removed when you reduce the number of rows by $11$ and increase the number of columns by $11$. So you want to know:

$$n-(r-11)(c+11) \\
  = rc-(rc-11c+11r-121)\\
  = 11c-11r+121\\
  = 11(c-r)+121$$

But we already know $c-r=15$, so you need to remove $11*15+121 = 286$.

Comment: The answer is 286... Not 154.

Comment: This is exactly right, but everywhere it says 'c-5' and 'c-11' it should be 'c+5' and 'c+11'. I got 286 following this method with the changes.

Comment: Fixed it now. I started with the given equation and didn't see it was incorrect.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see that I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

From this quote "I notice that if I remove $100$ toy soldiers, then I can arrange the remaining ones into a rectangular array with $5$ fewer rows and $5$ ***more*** columns," the correct equation is $$rc-100=(r-5)(c+5)\,.$$
That is, $$r-c=-15\,.$$
Thus,
$$(r-11)(c+11)=rc+11(r-c)-121=rc-11\cdot 15-121=rc-286\,.$$  Therefore, $286$ toys must be removed.